# How to trigger child element while clicking parent element on React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, parent-child

So I am doing a drum machine project on Freecodecamp, where I am failing this condition.

"
When I click on a .drum-pad element, the audio clip contained in its child  element should be triggered.
"
So how do I trigger child element(in this case the audio element,to play the audio) while clicking or pressing the parent element?

I wrote something like this

```
class Drumset extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }
 handleClick(e){
   this.inputElement.click()
 }
 
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="drum-machine" class="containerx box-middle">
          <div id="display">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <button type="button" class="drum-pad" id="Heater-1" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    Q
                    <audio
                      class="clip"
                      id="Q"
          src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3"
                      type="audio/mpeg"
                    ></audio>
```

Well I tried putting the onClick event on inner element, which doesn't work either.

Comment: use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-sound , its super easy and dont need to make audio tag for playing sound files.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your audio element by searching the DOM and then call `.play()` on it.

So your `onClick` handler becomes:

```js
handleClick(e){
   const audio = document.getElementById("Q");
   audio.play();
}
```

If you have multiple buttons all with only 1 audio tag inside, you can use one general `onClick` handler and get the child audio element from the target of the event.

```js
handleClick(e) {
    const audio = e.target.children[0];
    audio.play();
};
```

Comment: @leverglowhI have multiple buttons with multiple audio tags. Will the 2nd one work?

Comment: if you mean 1 button = 1 audio tag then yes, otherwise you will have to use something to track the number of children or simply use the first one (find by id).

Answer (score 0):

Hello write write this in inner click function

```
//innerclick function 
Const Innerclick(e)=>{
e.stoppropagation()
// do the job here
}
```

Jsx code  html here